# stemmed word using hunspell module

Tags: nlp, nltk, stemming, hunspell

I am using 2 modules for NLP one is nltk and the other is hunspell. The reason of using hunspell is that I have suffix and affix rules those needs to be followed.

```
from nltk.stem.porter import *
stemmer = PorterStemmer()
stemmer.stem('ladies')
```

> ladi

```
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
lemmatizer.lemmatize('ladies')
```

> lady

The nltk module works as expected as shown above. But hunspell module seems to support only lemmatization and there is no way to return stemmed form.

```
import hunspell
hobj = hunspell.HunSpell('en_US.dic', 'en_US.aff')
hobj.stem('ladies')
```

This returns "**lady**" and not "ladi" as one would expect. Is there any way to return the stemmed form of a word using hunspell module?

Comment: Because `stemmer != lemmatizer` and `(stemmer | lemmatizer) != spellchecker`. It's an XY sort of problem to conflate stemmer (Porter), lemmatizer (Wordnet morhpy) and spellchecker (Hunspell) ;P

Comment: @alvas, in my opinion with well written "dictionaries", hunspell is far more the a spellchecker (is is a lexical analyzer, including lemmatization) .